# Send a report via mail using oracle apex but not as an attachment

Tags: oracle

I want to send the contents of the report in the mail body instead of as an attacment in the oracle apex database application. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The body of the email can be almost any HTML you like, so if you render the report as HTML you can just add it to the email message.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.  I am a beginner in this.  I would greatly appreciate if you could elaborate on how to render the report as HTML.

Comment: There's a number of approaches you could take, depending on how exactly you want the email to look. The simplest method would probably be to use OWA_UTIL.cellsprint. See: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/w_util.htm#ARPLS70769

Comment: You could create an Apex page that renders the report as HTML, then call it using UTL_HTTP to get the rendered page as a CLOB.

Comment: But the way I'd do it is to run the query in PL/SQL, and create the HTML myself - that way I can control exactly the HTML including styles etc.

Comment: I am trying to implement this mail option in an already existing interactive report. If I create html myself, changes to the report from the added filter cannot be reflected in the mail. Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: You might be able to get what you want by starting with APEX_IR.get_report: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc/doc.42/e35127/apex_ir.htm#AEAPI29380 - but I'd say this might not be a task for a beginner - start with something a bit easier and work your way up.

Comment: Thank you so much for your timely reply.
could you please elaborate on how to retrieve the result from CELLSPRINT. I tried assigning it to a clob type. it didnt work.
could u please let me know the difference between htmldb_mail, utl_mail and apex_mail

Comment: This is when reading the documentation (linked above) is helpful. `cellsprint` is a *procedure*, not a function. It generates output to a web client, so it's not going to return the data to you directly. You might run it in a PL/SQL Process on another Apex page, for example. But I wouldn't recommend this method for use with your email solution.